# mostrar todos los registro menos el que busco

Tags: php, mysql

como hago para no mostrar este registro pero si los otros. Hasta ahí quede.

```
<?php
    include "codigo/conexion.php";
    $buscar = $_GET['producto']; 
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM catalogo where idcat = ".$buscar."";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $imagenes = $row['imagencat'];  
    ?>
    <img class="d-block img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo $imagenes ?>" >
    <?php } ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es mostrar todos los productos menos aquel con el id que pasas con el **$_GET**, debes hacer una negación utilizando el símbolo de exclamación **!** para filtrar por los resultados cuyo id sea diferente a **$buscar**, de esta forma.

> ```
> $consulta = "SELECT * FROM catalogo where idcat != ".$buscar."";
> ```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: De nada, un gusto ayudar.